# How react-date-picker auto correct on raw input

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

I have to explain the way `react-date-picker` auto-correct the date when enter raw string into input.

For example, I tried on the demo site of `react-date-picker`. (https://reactdatepicker.com/)

I typed `2019ab12` after blur by tab, I got the result `01/01/2019`

I typed `222` after blur by tab, I got the result `02/01/2019`

I typed `4444` after blur by tab, I got the result `01/01/444`

I can figure out the logic in some cases I've tried, but it is insufficient to confirm about the logic because my customers tried many cases and ask the question, **What kind of logic that we applied to turn the invalid date to the valid one**

My question is, does it (auto-correct behavior) follow any standard or it is just the implementation of this specific library.

Answer (score 0):

For those who have same questions as mine, please read the moment docs, parsing section to know the logic.

URL: https://momentjs.com/guides/#/parsing/.